# Gnome Power Profile Shows on Desktop Computer

Tags: gnome, 22.10

Since Ubuntu 22.04 I am seeing a "Power Profile" when looking at the settings as seen here:

[image]

Is there a reason why this shows on a Desktop Computer instead of only a Laptop computer? Does this affect CPU Performance, Graphics Performance, Memory Performance, SSD (Like NVMe) Performance.

And is there a way to simply remove it (In case it is only for Laptop power usage) from there and set it to a specific value.

I am not clear since it gives the impression is a Laptop concept to save power for battery life.

Comment: If you're using relatively recent hardware, then this will control the CPU governor and the temperature thresholds before throttling kicks in. Yes, even on desktop and workstation-grade machines. That said, if you use TLP to control this stuff, it will conflict with the Gnome tools and result in some weirdness.

Comment: @matigo can you let me know if running something like this can tell me if that button is actually doing anything cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor